# Grunt grunt-contrib-cssmin runs unending doesn't combine files

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am having a strange issue with grunt-contrib-cssmin. It never stops or gives errors. I am using

**C:\projects\doeclf>grunt --version && node --version && npm --version
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
v0.12.4
2.10.1**

My grunt.js has following in it

```
  cssmin: {
            target: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'css/',
                    src: ['index.css', '!*.min.css'],
                    dest: 'css/',
                    ext: '.min.css'
                }]
            }
        }
```

My project structure is as follows

```
 |
 |
 grunt.js 
 |
 |__css
    |
    |__index.css
```

When I run my grunt task this is the out it throws and it never finishes.

the output from my grunt cssmin --verbose is

```
    [4mInitializing[24m
Command-line options: [36m--verbose[39m

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...[32mOK[39m

[1mRegistering Gruntfile tasks.[22m
Reading package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing package.json...[32mOK[39m
Initializing config...[32mOK[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-requirejs" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-requirejs\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-requirejs\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "requirejs.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mrequirejs[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "compass.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mcompass[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "concat.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mconcat[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "connect.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mconnect[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mcssmin[39m

[1mRegistering "csswring" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\csswring\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\csswring\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "csswring.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mcsswring[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-sass" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-sass\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-sass\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "sass.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36msass[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36muglify[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "watch.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mwatch[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-express" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-express\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-express\package.json...[32mOK[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-parallel" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-express\node_modules\grunt-parallel\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-express\node_modules\grunt-parallel\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "parallel.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mparallel[39m
Loading "express.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mexpress[39m, [36mexpress-keepalive[39m, [36mexpress-restart[39m, [36mexpress-server[39m, [36mexpress-start[39m

[1mRegistering "grunt-open" local Npm module tasks.[22m
Reading C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-open\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Parsing C:\projects\doeclf\node_modules\grunt-open\package.json...[32mOK[39m
Loading "open.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mopen[39m
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mbuildsass[39m, [36mconcatcss[39m, [36mcssmin[39m, [36mdefault[39m, [36mserver[39m

Running tasks: [36mcssmin[39m

[4mRunning "cssmin" task[24m

[4mRunning "cssmin" task[24m

[4mRunning "cssmin" task[24m

[4mRunning "cssmin" task[24m

[4mRunning "cssmin" task[24m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target is fine and works perfectly, so the issue is somewhere else in your code.

Specifically, your last line shows that you are redefining your own `cssmin` task
`Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...[32mOK[39m
+ [36mbuildsass[39m, [36mconcatcss[39m, [36mcssmin[39m, [36mdefault[39m, [36mserver[39m`

This probably causes the infinite looping, call your own task another name  (mincss?) and you should be fine.